# How do I pass a variable from a link to a controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a page setup with a table of items. In each row there is a link. When the link is clicked I want to pass the ID of them through to the controller so I can pass it on to another view. Although I can't figure out how to do this.

This is the code in my item view

```
                @foreach($items as $item)
                <tr>
                        <td>{{$item->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$item->genre}}</td>
                        <td>{{$item->description}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ url('/rent') }}">View</a></td>
                      </tr>
                @endforeach
```

As you can see there is a link which leads me to the rent view. In the controller this is all I have.

```
public function rent()
{  
    return view('rent');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it something like this.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
 <tr>
   <td>{{$item->title}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->genre}}</td>
   <td>{{$item->description}}</td>
   <td><a href="{{ route('/rent', [ 'id' => $item->valueYouWantToPass ])}}">View</a></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

And then inside your controller you can accept the the value you are passing.

```
public function rent($value)
{
    return View::make('new-view')->with('value', $value);
}
```

and then inside your new-view.blade.php

```
<p> The value I passed is: {{ $value }} </p>
```

Read more about Laravel url helpers here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls

Answer (score 0):

You can use `route()` helper:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->genre }</td>
        <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('rent', ['id' => $item->someId]) }}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

As alternative you can use link to action:

```
{{ action('RentController@profile', ['id' => $item->someId]); }}
```

And sometimes it's useful to use `url()` helper:

```
{{ echo url('rent', [$item->someId]) }}
```

More on these helpes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls).

If you're using Laravel 5 with Laravel Collective installed or you're on Laravel 4, you can use [these constructions](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#generating-urls) to generate URLs with parameters.

PS: If you're using tables for layout, don't do it. You should learn DIVs, because it's really easy now to build cool layout with DIVs using Bootstrap framework which is built-in Laravel.